# React-admin TypeError: dynamicSheet.update(...) is undefined

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-admin

I'm trying to complete the tutorial on https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html
when I add

```
<Resource name="users" list={ListGuesser} />
```

to my src/App.js and run with yarn start or npm start I get the following error in browser:

```
TypeError: dynamicSheet.update(...) is undefined
attach
node_modules/@material-ui/styles/esm/makeStyles/makeStyles.js:119
```

I have tried upgrading packages and installing everything from scratch but nothing seem to work.
Does anybody know why is this happening and how to fix it?
I'm on mac os mojave, npm 6.13.4, working with react-admin ^3.0.0

Comment: Do you have `@material-ui/core` in your package.json?

Comment: yes `"@material-ui/core": "^4.8.1"` and `"material-ui": "^0.20.2"` are in my package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any info about it on the internet, but I suggest that you create an issue on the GitHub repository of Material UI: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues.

There is something a bit similar in [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19005) issue. I don't know if it could help, but it might.

Comment: I confirm adding "jss": "10.0.0" to dependencies in package.json removed the problem! which appears to be a temporary fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue: dynamicSheet.update(...) is undefined in @material-ui/core 4.8.0.

A quick fix would be adding the following to your `package.json`

```
 "resolutions": {
    "jss": "10.0.0"
  },
```

and updating your MUI dependencies:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.8.1",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.37",
"@material-ui/styles": "^4.7.1",
```

[Review issues here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues)